# When does a map of spheres (controvariantly) induce a morphism on homotopy groups?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Maybe this is trivial, but given a map $f: S^k \to S^n$ and a space $X$, when is
$$
\pi_n(X) = [S^n, X]_\ast \xrightarrow{f^\ast} [S^k, X] = \pi_k(X)
$$
a group homomorphism? Here $f^\ast$ denotes precomposition in the homotopy classes.

This map is well defined, and I know that if $S^k \xrightarrow{f} S^n = \Sigma S^{k-1} \xrightarrow{\Sigma g} \Sigma S^{n-1}$ for some map $g: S^{k-1} \to S^{n-1}$, then the above works since for $\alpha, \beta \in [\Sigma S^{n-1}, X]_\ast = \pi_n(X)$ we can  define the group operation as
$$
 (\alpha+\beta)(x \wedge t) = \begin{cases}
  \alpha(x \wedge 2t) & 0 \leq t \leq 1/2 \\
  \beta(x \wedge (2t-1)) & 1/2 \leq t \leq 1,
 \end{cases}
 $$
and then
\begin{align*}
  \Sigma g^\ast (\alpha+\beta) (z \wedge t)= (\alpha+\beta) \circ \Sigma g (z \wedge t) = (\alpha+\beta)(g(z) \wedge t) = (\alpha \circ \Sigma g + \beta \circ \Sigma g) (z \wedge t),
 \end{align*}
but does this hold more in general?

The reason I'm asking is because I believe that if we take $f: S^1 \xrightarrow{z^2} S^1$, then $f^\ast$ should be multiplication by $2$ on the fundamental group, but I don't really see why.

Comment: The group structure on $\pi_n$ arises from cogroup structure on $S^n$. So naturally if $f$ preserves cogroup structure this will hold. And this coincides with your observations on suspension, because suspension is always a cogroup. However I'm not even sure  if there are maps that are not cogroup morphisms.

Comment: Well, the Hopf map $\eta:S^3\rightarrow S^2$ is quadratic in the sense that the induced map $\eta^*:\pi_2S^2\rightarrow\pi_3S^2$ satisfies $\eta^*(f)=(\deg(f))^2\cdot\eta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the abstract nonsense: The group structure on homotopy groups comes from a cogroup structure on the spheres $S^n,\,n\ge1$ (in the category of pointed topological spaces), also called a co-H space. For a (pointed homotopy class of a) pointed map $f\colon S^k\rightarrow S^n$ to induce a group homomorphism after applying $[-,X]_{\ast}$ for any space $X$ is, by the Yoneda lemma, equivalent to asking that the map $f$ is a cogroup homomorphism, also called a co-H map.

Now, for any pointed space $X$, the pointed suspension $\Sigma X$ has a natural co-H space structure. For $X=S^n$, this is precisely the usual co-H space structure on $\Sigma X=S^{n+1}$ (or perhaps the opposite one, depending on chosen orientation). You are correct to observe that, in general, if $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ is a pointed map, the suspended map $\Sigma f\colon\Sigma X\rightarrow\Sigma Y$ is a co-H map with respect to these structures.

In particular, the calculation of $\pi_n(S^n)=\mathbb{Z}$ for $n\ge1$ and the notion of degree imply that any pointed map $S^n\rightarrow S^n$ for $n\ge2$ is (up to pointed homotopy) the suspension of the pointed map $S^{n-1}\rightarrow S^{n-1}$ of the same degree, hence a co-H map. For pointed maps $S^1\rightarrow S^1$, the only evident pointed suspensions are the constant map and the identity. The other maps $S^1\rightarrow S^1$ are in fact not co-H maps, for the degree $n$ map $f_n\colon S^1\rightarrow S^1$ induces the $n$-th power map $[f_n]^{\ast}\colon\pi_1(X)\rightarrow\pi_1(X),\,[\gamma]\mapsto[\gamma]^n$. This is not generally a group homomorphism, as one can check with the universal example $X=S^1\vee S^1$.

The general case of pointed maps $S^n\rightarrow S^m$ is hard. If $n<m$, any such map is nullhomotopic and trivially a co-H map. If $n=m$, this has been taken care of, so assume $n>m$. The [Freudenthal suspension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freudenthal_suspension_theorem) implies that the suspension map $\Sigma\colon\pi_{i-1}(S^{n-1})\rightarrow\pi_i(S^n)$ is surjective for $i\le 2n-2$, so any map $S^i\rightarrow S^n$ with $i\le 2n-2$ is a (pointed) suspension and hence a co-H map.

It is not too hard to prove that the (pointed) mapping cone of a co-H map between co-H spaces is a co-H space. This allows us to construct non-co-H maps immediately outisde the Freudenthal suspension range. For $n$ even, the [Hopf invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_invariant) is a non-trivial homomorphism $H\colon\pi_{2n-1}(S^n)\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ and the adjunction space obtained by attaching a cell along a map with non-trivial Hopf invariant has non-trivial cup products in positive degrees (by definition), yet that cannot happen for a co-H space (exercise). Thus, such maps are not co-H maps, e.g. the Whitehead product of $\mathrm{id}_{S^n}$ with itself.

There are, in fact, also co-H maps between spheres that are not suspensions, e.g. a map $S^{2p}\rightarrow S^3$ representing an element of order $p$ in $\pi_{2p}(S^3)$, where $p$ is an odd prime. This, among other things, is due to Bernstein and Hilton in "Category and Generalized Hopf Invariants". You can also read Martin Arkowitz' article "Co-H-Spaces" published in the "Handbook of Algebraic Topology" for a neat overview. In fact, the co-H maps between spheres are completely characterized by Bernstein and Hilton in terms of these "generalized Hopf invariants", although they are quite involved.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and clear answer! I didn't know about much of this; you say "for the degree $n$ map $f_n\colon S^1\rightarrow S^1$ induces the $n$-th power map $[f_n]^{\ast}\colon\pi_1(X)\rightarrow\pi_1(X),\,[\gamma]\mapsto[\gamma]^n$", but is this a triviality? Because I can't straightly see it.

Comment: If $\gamma$ is a loop in $X$, then $\gamma\circ f_n$ is the loop in $X$ that traverses $\gamma$ a total of $n$ times at constant speed. For $n=2$, this is $\gamma^2$ by the definition. For other $n$, the $n$-fold composition of $\gamma$ with itself depends on how you bracket it and will not equal $\gamma\circ f_n$ as a loop. However, they are (piece-wise linear) reparametrizations of another. In proving that the product on $\pi_1$ is associative, you will have proven that such reparametrizations do not change the homotopy class, so that $[\gamma\circ f_n]=[\gamma]^n$.

Comment: (For negative $n$, you also have to take into account that the inverse on $\pi_1$ is given by traversing the loop backwards.)